# Issue sending JSON in POST request to Play App

Tags: angularjs, post, playframework, request, http-status-code-404

i am working on a project using Play Framework 2.4 using a simple Java template, as in many documentation i have seen, i just wrote a simple controller with my business methods and put the necessary paths on my route's file.

Now i am writing a client in Angular.js to invoke the logic written in the play app. It had work perfectly with GET methods, but when i try to do a POST from angular using the next lines:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url : rootURL + '/user/company',
        data : {id : '123456' , name: 'xxxxxx'}
});
```

I receive a 404 Error. After several hours of forums searching, i found that the Play App is expecting **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** in the request content-type header.

So i modify my Angular call to the following:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url : rootURL + '/user/company',
        data : {id : '123456' , name: 'xxxxx'},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest: function(obj){
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
        }

    })
};
```

And the POST works perfectly on this way, but i wonder, is there any way so i can make a POST request to my play app where the content-type is set to application/json? How can achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Here is my controller code:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

     public Result myAction(){
         //do funny stuffs              
     }
}
```

And my route file has the following

```
POST    /path/action               controllers.MyController.myAction()
```

Comment: I have exactly the same architecture as yours and I don't need to add these extra settings for my `$http` requests. Show us your controller and your routes file

Comment: @c4k just update my question whit that info.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added  @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class) in your action method?

Also when you are doing POST to a different domain,  first check you request to see if it's a POST, I don't know about AngularJS, but with Polymer, it sent a OPTION first during ajax POST to different domain, and I met very similar issue (wrong content type and 404) which is resolved by implementing an OPTION on server which accept POST.

To Fix that, you need to manually implement an OPTION, here's what to do:

First, In your routes file, add an entry to accept OPTION

```
OPTIONS    /*url                controllers.Application.optionCheck(url)
```

Then implement the optionCheck method which accept everything

```
    public Result optionCheck(String url){
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, origin, Content-type, x-json, x-prototype-version, x-requested-with");
    return ok();
}
```

And that's it

Comment: No i dont, i just update my question so you can see how my action method is right now, it is necessary this annotation?

Also, by now i am just using Angular, but in the next iteration i should include Polymer on my client. I am having the exact behavior you describe, when i do the post, angular first send an OPTIONS request. Do i need to implement a response for the OPTIONS request? This is not in the official documentation, so i am a little confuse, thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Also I think you need to add a @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class) on top of your POST method so it accept json type.